# Testing against testcases - how it is formally called?

Tags: testing, methodology

Preparing test strategy, I have run into this simple (not so simple as I could not find the right name for that) problem - is there any name for this testing?
I defined the testing needed as manual testing done according by gray box strategy..but as it is testing against testcases, how is it called? The opposite would be exploratory testing. Thanks :)

Comment: May be it helps to to ask yourself: What would be the **opposite** of "Testing against testcases "? **Intuitive** or **non systematic** testing?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean testing where a test case is already specified and someone is just executing the predefined scripts, I've usually seen this referred to as scripted testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the testing of test cases and other testing-related products (such as test data sets and test scripts), that is often called **meta-testing**.